# Calculate Age based on Birthday for each Div

Tags: jquery

I have a JQuery code to calculate the age based on a date but I can't seem to apply on more than one Div

```
<div class="bday">
     <span id="age"></span>
     <span id="birthdate">01/21/1983</span>
</div>
<div class="bday">
     <span id="age"></span>
     <span id="birthdate">01/21/1982</span>
</div>
<div class="bday">
     <span id="age"></span>
     <span id="birthdate">01/21/1981</span>
</div>

$('#birthdate').each(function() {
    var ptag = $(this).text();
    var birthdate = new Date(ptag);
    var cur = new Date();
    var diff = cur - birthdate;
    var age = Math.floor(diff / 31536000000);
    $('#age').append(age);
});
```

I have tired classes but the all of the ages appear in each span. 
What else can I do to have this code apply to every div rather than it appearing on one div?

Comment: you can't use many id as same name. use class for this.

Comment: `id` is supposed to be unique and used for a single element on a page. `class` should be used when you need to select multiple elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i commented your question, you have to change all the is to class and then use closest function fir finding the parent and then find for the another child that is sibling of the birthday.

And also you can't use the append, cause it will append all the time with previous data. so use text() or html().

**Your modified jQuery:**

```
$('.birthdate').each(function() {
    var ptag = $(this).text();
    var birthdate = new Date(ptag);
    var cur = new Date();
    var diff = cur - birthdate;
    var age = Math.floor(diff / 31536000000);
    $(this).closest("div").find('.age').html(age);
});
```

**Your Modified HTML:**

```
<div class="bday">
     <span class="age"></span>
     <span class="birthdate">01/21/1983</span>
</div>
<div class="bday">
     <span class="age"></span>
     <span class="birthdate">01/21/1982</span>
</div>
<div class="bday">
     <span class="age"></span>
     <span class="birthdate">01/21/1981</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank-you for your effort

Comment: Why you are copy paste answer? Frayne Konok

Comment: What you are saying?? @javedrathod

Comment: @javedrathod, Checkout my response of this question in the comment. Then blame me, I did this thing in my local then i post this answer t this question. I am not a copier.

Comment: i just say you copy my answer. and change only ".bday" to div

Comment: @javedrathod, No sir, I did it in my way, may be our thinking little bit similar. But its not true that i copy your code. Because i did this in my local PC for testing purpose so i got late to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please Use This HTML :

```
<div class="bday">
     <span class="age"></span>
     <span class="birthdate">01/21/1983</span>
</div>
<div class="bday">
     <span class="age"></span>
     <span class="birthdate">01/21/1982</span>
</div>
<div class="bday">
     <span class="age"></span>
     <span class="birthdate">01/21/1981</span>
</div>
```

PLease Use This Script :

```
$('.birthdate').each(function() {
    var ptag = $(this).text();
    var birthdate = new Date(ptag);
    var cur = new Date();
    var diff = cur - birthdate;
    var age = Math.floor(diff / 31536000000);
    $(this).closest('.bday').find(".age").text(age);
});
```

I Change only id To Class and append line.

Comment: Thank-you for your efforts!